SCAN function fails to show the steps followed by the REDUCE function when calculating
Let me show you what I want to achieve:

I start with a range of figures and I want to see how the range is built horizontally, one figure at a time.
I am able to get the last line of the result by using a REDUCE function. Until here, everything is fine.
However, if I want to see how the REDUCE function has built its result, line by line, and I try it by replacing REDUCE with SCAN, I simply get a #CALC! error. I simply do not understand it.
In my way of understanding these two functions, if one works, so should it the other.
Any suggestions?

With the exception of REDUCE, the LAMBDA helper functions in Excel cannot return arrays per iteration. If you want to see the intermediate steps, you can still do it using REDUCE by vertically stacking the accumulator with VSTACK and replacing every occurrence of the accumulator a with TAKE(a;-1):
=DROP(REDUCE(0;B4:B6;LAMBDA(a;b;VSTACK(a;HSTACK(TAKE(a;-1);b))));1;1)



Not sure what you're using it for, but MAKEARRAY may be a good choice of weapons here:
=MAKEARRAY(3,3,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r>=c,c,"")))
Or using range, like in example:
=LET(a,A1:A3,b,ROWS(a),MAKEARRAY(b,b,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r>=c,INDEX(a,c),""))))
Where MAKEARRAY creates a grid the size of 3*3 (number of rows of range). r is the row number of the grid, c the column number.
If r is greater than or equal to c then index the range with c-number as the row index. Else show a blank cell.
Especially on larger ranges this performs better than REDUCE combined with VSTACK.
Else this works as well =DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:A3,LAMBDA(x,y,IFNA(VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(,y)),""))),1)
Or with text: =LET(a,A1:A3,DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,IFNA(VSTACK(x,INDEX(a,SEQUENCE(,y))),""))),1))
This uses the sequence of the number of rows of the range as an accumulator. It stacks the first result (INDEX(range,ROW(sequence(1)))) with the next (INDEX(range,ROW(sequence(2)))), etc.
DROP is used to drop the initial x value (0).
Or without lambda:
=LET(a,A1:A3,b,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),c,TOROW(b),IF(c>b,"",INDEX(a,b+c-b)))
